# Python: I need percentage from a count of visits on locations (- for each customerID)

Tags: python, pandas

The task is to create a column which translate a numeric representation of visits on a location (per customer) into a percentage representation. This is necessary because I have to track if the customer changes pattern. Please see this
[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0IUC.png)

It is important that the percentage is for each customer which means: for each customer the sum needs to be 100%. I have been using the pandas library to get the numeric representation (NumberVisits)

I hope one of you geniuses are able to help me out here.

Best regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can create the new column by doing the following:

```
   df["% visit"] = (df.NumberVisit/ df.NumberVisit.sum()) *100
```

If i understood you right you may want:

```
   result_df = df.groupby(['sub_acc','your_other_columns']).agg({'numbervisit': 'sum'})
   result_df = result_df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:100 * x / float(x.sum()))
```

I get

[my results on dummy data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVY9k.png)

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply! However I need the column to sum = 100% for each customer and not sum to 100% for all customers. For example if CustomerID had 3 locations, I want those 3 locations to sum to 100% based on NumberVisit